# Convert string into code symbols by pl/sql

Tags: oracle, utf-8, plsql

I have to convert string in my local language into UTF code symbols (I suppose it is UTF code simbols) using pl/sql.

For example the initial string is: "шт", the target string should be `&#1096;&#1090;`

Is there any ideas how to that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion of all Win-1251 symbols to UTF:
Lengthy, but does not depend on server codepage :-)

```
S := REPLACE(S,'Ђ','&#1026;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ѓ','&#1027;');
S := REPLACE(S,'‚','&#8218;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ѓ','&#1107;');
S := REPLACE(S,'„','&#8222;');
S := REPLACE(S,'…','&#8230;');
S := REPLACE(S,'†','&#8224;');
S := REPLACE(S,'‡','&#8225;');
S := REPLACE(S,'€','&#8364;');
S := REPLACE(S,'‰','&#8240;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Љ','&#1033;');
S := REPLACE(S,'‹','&#8249;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Њ','&#1034;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ќ','&#1036;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ћ','&#1035;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Џ','&#1039;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ђ','&#1106;');
S := REPLACE(S,'‘','&#8216;');
S := REPLACE(S,'’','&#8217;');
S := REPLACE(S,'“','&#8220;');
S := REPLACE(S,'”','&#8221;');
S := REPLACE(S,'•','&#8226;');
S := REPLACE(S,'–','&#8211;');
S := REPLACE(S,'—','&#8212;');
S := REPLACE(S,'™','&#8482;');
S := REPLACE(S,'љ','&#1113;');
S := REPLACE(S,'›','&#8250;');
S := REPLACE(S,'њ','&#1114;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ќ','&#1116;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ћ','&#1115;');
S := REPLACE(S,'џ','&#1119;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ў','&#1038;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ў','&#1118;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ј','&#1032;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ґ','&#1168;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ё','&#1025;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Є','&#1028;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ї','&#1031;');
S := REPLACE(S,'І','&#1030;');
S := REPLACE(S,'і','&#1110;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ґ','&#1169;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ё','&#1105;');
S := REPLACE(S,'№','&#8470;');
S := REPLACE(S,'є','&#1108;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ј','&#1112;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ѕ','&#1029;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ѕ','&#1109;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ї','&#1111;');
S := REPLACE(S,'А','&#1040;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Б','&#1041;');
S := REPLACE(S,'В','&#1042;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Г','&#1043;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Д','&#1044;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Е','&#1045;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ж','&#1046;');
S := REPLACE(S,'З','&#1047;');
S := REPLACE(S,'И','&#1048;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Й','&#1049;');
S := REPLACE(S,'К','&#1050;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Л','&#1051;');
S := REPLACE(S,'М','&#1052;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Н','&#1053;');
S := REPLACE(S,'О','&#1054;');
S := REPLACE(S,'П','&#1055;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Р','&#1056;');
S := REPLACE(S,'С','&#1057;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Т','&#1058;');
S := REPLACE(S,'У','&#1059;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ф','&#1060;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Х','&#1061;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ц','&#1062;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ч','&#1063;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ш','&#1064;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Щ','&#1065;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ъ','&#1066;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ы','&#1067;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ь','&#1068;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Э','&#1069;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Ю','&#1070;');
S := REPLACE(S,'Я','&#1071;');
S := REPLACE(S,'а','&#1072;');
S := REPLACE(S,'б','&#1073;');
S := REPLACE(S,'в','&#1074;');
S := REPLACE(S,'г','&#1075;');
S := REPLACE(S,'д','&#1076;');
S := REPLACE(S,'е','&#1077;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ж','&#1078;');
S := REPLACE(S,'з','&#1079;');
S := REPLACE(S,'и','&#1080;');
S := REPLACE(S,'й','&#1081;');
S := REPLACE(S,'к','&#1082;');
S := REPLACE(S,'л','&#1083;');
S := REPLACE(S,'м','&#1084;');
S := REPLACE(S,'н','&#1085;');
S := REPLACE(S,'о','&#1086;');
S := REPLACE(S,'п','&#1087;');
S := REPLACE(S,'р','&#1088;');
S := REPLACE(S,'с','&#1089;');
S := REPLACE(S,'т','&#1090;');
S := REPLACE(S,'у','&#1091;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ф','&#1092;');
S := REPLACE(S,'х','&#1093;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ц','&#1094;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ч','&#1095;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ш','&#1096;');
S := REPLACE(S,'щ','&#1097;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ъ','&#1098;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ы','&#1099;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ь','&#1100;');
S := REPLACE(S,'э','&#1101;');
S := REPLACE(S,'ю','&#1102;');
S := REPLACE(S,'я','&#1103;');
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a bit long procedure :-), but seems it works very well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for convert?

```
select CONVERT('шт', 'AL32UTF8', 'CL8MSWIN1251') from dual
```

I have not run it, because I am using UTF throuout DB, but you may need to play around with encodings.

And here is a link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm

Comment: Thank you, but seems it's not what I'm looking for.
What I've got when I run it in sql-plus

>select CONVERT('шт', 'AL32UTF8', 'CL8MSWIN1251') from dual
  2  /

CONV
----
С€С‚